# Clone divs from a tab menu and stack them on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I need help on how I can clone div and display them on top of each other.

Here is the scenario:

**1.) I want each of the divs under this tabs to be stacked up on each other. (Screenshot #1)**

Screenshot #1
[image: Screenshot 1]

**2:) Here's how the div looks under the map tab.**

Screenshot #2
[image: Screenshot 2]

**3:) I tried to clone the map so it will show above the "Property Features", but it just showed blank above the "Property Features" div after the page load.**

**Here is the code that I used.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery('#ihf-map-tab-content').append(jQuery('#ihf-detail-features-tab').remove().clone(true)).html();
});
```

Screenshot #3
[image: Screenshot 3]

**4:) I still need to click the map tab so the map will show above the "Property Feature"**

Screenshot #4
[image: Screenshot 4]

**Can you Please help me on how can I clone the divs under the tabs and display perfectly?**

Here is the Sample link from the live site:
http://www.nikkibascon.com/homes-for-sale-details/217-S-STANLEY-DRIVE-BEVERLY-HILLS-CA-90211/16149602/306/

But I am editing this feature on my localhost first, so it wont show on live yet.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: give plz link to page with map...

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the live link sample.
http://www.nikkibascon.com/homes-for-sale-details/217-S-STANLEY-DRIVE-BEVERLY-HILLS-CA-90211/16149602/306/

I am only editing it on my localhost first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery('#ihf-detail-features-tab').prepend(jQuery('#ihf-map-tab-content').children('.row').clone(true));
});
```

Comment: Too bad no luck. >.<
The Featured Property div is gone when I paste that code.

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the live link sample.
http://www.nikkibascon.com/homes-for-sale-details/217-S-STANLEY-DRIVE-BEVERLY-HILLS-CA-90211/16149602/306/

I am only editing it on my localhost first.

thanks

Comment: @MarkLozano i update code check plz, i now dont have time if u dont found solution, i help you later...

Comment: Still no luck, On first load it just show the "Featured property" div.
I still need to click the "map" tab so it will show above the "Featured property" div.

No worries, Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: @MarkLozano on your site using cms wordpress map created in plugin optima express, go to settings find short code of map and paste where u need...

Comment: unfortunately, I can't do that cause the map is dynamically generated on that page and there is no shortcode for the map.

Comment: u can't clone map with all functional, search solution in wordpress plugin, map generates with js in this plugin...

Comment: how map was inserted on this tab ?